# How to register a receiver in the main activity?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-activity

I have a `SmsReceiver` class that I want to register in the main activity, what exactly should I do ?

I am new to Android.

Comment: You can take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660823/android-alarm-not-working/4661122#4661122

Comment: There is plenty of answers on this topic. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4805733/1521064), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134203/how-to-use-registerreceiver-method) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508300/how-to-register-broadcast-receiver).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you can do 2 things:

1. Create and define `BroadcastReceiver` in the `Manifest`
2. Create and register the `BroadcastReceiver` in code.

For option 2 (which you are asking):

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` in code (MyBroadcastReceiver).
Declare MyBroadcastReceiver in the scope of your `Activity`:

```
MyBroadcastReceiver mMyBroadcastReceiver;
```

Register the `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` by:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED);
this.registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

For API level 19 and above

```
 IntentFilter smsFilter = new IntentFilter();
 smsFilter.addAction(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
registerReceiver(this.receiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //some action
   }
};

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("YOUR_ACTION");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

As you've asked to register `BroadcastReceiver` inside your `MainActivity` that fits to `registerReceiver-codewise-inside-MainActivity`

Here's what code looks like ==>

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver;
private IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter(android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED);

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    registerReceiver(smsReceiver, myFilter); // register BroadCastReceiver at time of initialization of Activity with proper Intent-Filter
   }

@Override
  protected void onPause() 
   {
    unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver); // UnRegister BroadCastReceiver as you no longer have your activity at Foreground -- Saving CPU & Battery Drainage
    super.onPause();
   }

 @Override
   protected void onResume() 
   {
    registerReceiver(smsReceiver, myFilter); // Register BroadCastReceiver Once again as your activity comes from pause to forground state again.
    super.onResume();
   }

  smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() //Implementation of your BroadCastReceiver
  {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       // Do whatever you like as sms is received and caught by these BroadCastReceiver
        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
    }
  };
 }
```