# how to Create and register the BroadcastReceiver in code

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i am new on android .
I am trying register the BroadcastReceiver in code at my activity. this is my code:

MyReciever class:

```
public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("===>", "onReceive: "+  intent.getAction());
    Toast.makeText(context, "I got it "+ intent.getIntExtra("MyValue",0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

myActivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myReciever = new MyReciever();
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("test");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(myReciever, intentFilter);
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.safarayaneh.mybroadcastreciever">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

when i run my app, nothing happen and toast not comes up! I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397336/how-to-register-a-receiver-in-the-main-activity) and [this](http://code4reference.com/2012/09/register-unregiste-broadcast-receiver-part/) article and i don't understand that where is my problem.

Comment: Which broadcast are you expecting to receive? I don't see anything that's sending a broadcast with the `"test"` action.

Comment: @MikeM. you mean is that i have to use broadcast intent?

Comment: Yeah, something has to broadcast an `Intent` your Receiver is registered for. Otherwise, nothing is going to happen.

Comment: @MikeM. but some tutorial did not use of broadcast intent? like this:http://code4reference.com/2012/09/register-unregiste-broadcast-receiver-part/

Comment: That example is registering for the `"android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"` broadcast, which is sent by the system every minute. Nothing is sending a broadcast with your custom action `"test"`.

Comment: @MikeM. Then i have to add reciver tag to manifest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146492/discussion-between-sayres-kabir-and-mike-m).

Comment: I have changed all thing that you said , but still does not work: http://codepad.org/W9Nl2TXD

Comment: The `onCreate()` method runs before `onResume()`, so you're sending the broadcast before you've registered the Receiver. Beyond that, if you mean to do this all dynamically in your code, you don't need the manifest element for your Receiver.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you ,finally it is work .

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private IntentFilter intentFilter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //this line makes the broadcastreceiver
        BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "I got it "+ intent.getIntExtra("MyValue",0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        //this line register broadcastreceiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("test"));

        //this line calls the broadcastreceiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent("test"));
    }    

}
```

Comment: I wrote the steps for you in comments

Comment: thank dude.i gave you positive for your helping. but solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Register your broadCast receiver in OnResume and unregister it in OnPause like this

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myReciever = new MyReciever();
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("test");
}

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(reMyreceive);
     }
     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onResume();

          registerReceiver(reMyreceive, filter);
     }
```