# Dynamically registering BroadcastReceiver - Receiver not registered

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I've a problem with dynamically registering BroacasrReceiver `CallReceiver`. When `onReceive` method of `CallReceiver` is trigerred the fatal exception is thrown.

```
...
private boolean isCRRegistered = false;

public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

     if(!isCRRegistered)    {
     IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
     CallReceiver mCallReceiver = new CallReceiver();
     registerReceiver(mCallReceiver, filter2);

     //registering some listener
     mCallReceiver.registerListener(this);
     }
}
```

unregistering:

```
if(isCRRegistered)  {
        unregisterReceiver (mCallReceiver);
}
```

logcat:

```
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x20000000 (has extras) } in com.kris.intellignetringer.CallReceiver@448162b8
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:934)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.kris.intellignetringer.ScreenReceiver@44816d60
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.forgetReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:812)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:822)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at com.kris.intellignetringer.StateChecker.serviceDestroy(StateChecker.java:126)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at com.kris.intellignetringer.StateChecker.onPhoneStateChange(StateChecker.java:36)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at com.kris.intellignetringer.CallReceiver.onReceive(CallReceiver.java:50)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    at  android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:917)
02-04 14:41:50.286: E/AndroidRuntime(28328):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508300/how-to-register-broadcast-receiver

Comment: My answer to your previous question catches the `IllegalArgumentException` when you try to unregister.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is not here! The error is when you are unregistering the receiver. It seems you are conditionally registering the receiver.

Therefore, before unregistering the receiver, make sure that you have really registered it.

You can make use of a boolean that is set once you register the receiver. Then when you want to unregister the receiver, you make sure that the boolean is set otherwise(if it is not(false)) you do not unregister.

Comment: Following your suggestion I've updated my code, but the same problem is still there.

Comment: @soulreaver Are you sure this is the only place where you call `unregisterReceiver`!?